# How to use a list inside Compile—it says it should be a machine-size real number?

Tags: list-manipulation, compile

Super simple question, but I'm lost here.

```
f = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {c, _Real}}, 
  x /. NSolve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, {x}]]
f[1., -4., -5.]
```

gives the error

```
CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression {-1.,5.} should be a machine-size real number.
```

But

```
g = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {c, _Real}}, 
  x /. NSolve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, {x}][[1]]]
g[1., -4., -5.]
```

works fine.

How do I type the result so that it knows it's a list. I haven't had any problems getting Compile to return a list before, and

```
h = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {c, _Real}}, 
  sol = NSolve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, {x}]; {x /. sol[[1]], 
   x /. sol[[2]]}]
h[1., -4., -5.]
```

gets around the issue, but there's got to be a better way than that.

This gives the same error, even though the output should be a real number. Somehow the list can't exist within the compiled function. I don't understand.

```
k = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {c, _Real}}, 
  listofSolutions = x /. NSolve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, {x}]; 
  listofSolutions[[1]]]
k[1., -4., -5.]
```

Edited to add: I know NSolve isn't compilable; I'm trying to get the speed up from the typing of a, b, and c, among other things in my actual code.

Comment: `ReplaceAll` and `NSolve` are not [compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions).  Just get rid of `Compile`.

Comment: I don't know what speed-up you mean.  Compile is likely to slow things down in this case.  Compared to the slowness of `NSolve`, though, it will be negligible....Okay, I guess I can imagine a use-case that this would be reasonable.  You should `Block`/`Module`/localize `x`, though, to protect the code when `x` has a global value.  (And thanks for the accept. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Maybe I'm mistaken, but I'm solving the same polynomial with different parameter values and I want to save that structure and feed in (typed) parameter values. I thought that Compile would help. And NSolve seems to take forever for sure. I've been trying to switch to Root with a few different starting points.

Comment: You know about `CompilePrint` to inspect what the compiler is doing? (``Needs@"CompiledFunctionTools`"; CompilePrint[f]``)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [my comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225616/how-to-use-a-list-inside-compile-it-says-it-should-be-a-machine-size-real-number#comment574211_225616), but here goes:

```
f = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}, {c, _Real}},
   x /. NSolve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, {x}],
   {{ReplaceAll[_, _], _Real, 1}}];  (* <-- return type declarations *)
f[1., -4., -5.]

(*  {-1., 5.}  *)
```

If you have many different kinds of calls to `ReplaceAll`, you can make more specific patterns.  For example:

```
{{ReplaceAll[_, _NSolve], _Real, 1}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I could have figured that out on my own.

Comment: @NathanRL  You're welcome.  It's the last paradigm at the top of the docs of `Compile`, but it is documented elsewhere:  See "External Calls" in the [compiler tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compile/tutorial/Overview.html)